# JavaScript String Literal That Calls Function for Specific Instance of an Object

Tags: javascript

This is simplified code for a more complex thing I'm working on.  The code works but a certain part of it doesn't feel right.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish a certain part of this.

https://jsfiddle.net/fkyLy3of/36/

```
window.getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

window.mySingleton = {
    runMe: function(obj) {
        var uid = getRandomInt(0, 999999);

        // START OF CODE IN QUESTION
        window.mySingleton['whoAmI' + uid] = function() {
            alert(obj.firstName);
        };

        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML += '<input type="button" onclick="window.mySingleton.whoAmI' + uid + '()" value="Click Me">';
        // END OF CODE IN QUESTION
    }
};

//simulate launching panel xyz
var person1 = new Object();
person1.firstName = "John";
window['mySingleton']['runMe'](person1);

//simulate launching a second instance of panel xyz
var person2 = new Object();
person2.firstName = "Jane";
window['mySingleton']['runMe'](person2);
```

My question is about the code in between the comments.  When I have a JavaScript string literal like this how can I go about getting it to reference the correct instance of an object?  This code works, the first button accurately references John, and the second references Jane.  But using this approach, if 20 panels are launched this will create 20 versions of `whoAmI`.

obj = An empty DHTMLX window.

singleton = The screen (grid, form, etc...) that goes into the obj (the DHTMLX window).

I can only edit the content within the `runMe` function.  Since I cannot rearchitect everything I think what I have above will have to do unless someone can think of a better way.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean `20 versions of whoAmI`?

Comment: The 6 lines of code at the end simulate launching a panel (a screen or window in an webapp).  The result is the creation of 2 whoAmI functions because of the unique ID added to the end of the function name.  So if I stick with this approach, and 20 panels end up being opened, then I will have 20 whoAmI[someRandomInt] functions.  I feel like there is a better way to architected this so that the correct instance of an object can be called from the string.  I tried removing the `onclick`, giving the button an `id` and adding an onclick event to it via JS passing it the obj but that didn't work

Comment: This is very strange code. I don't think it's really doing what you think it is. It's not actually doing anything random. It's just creating a series of buttons which alert a string that you're passing to the button. Also if it's a singleton then there should only be one instance of the object. That's the point of a singleton. I don't understand the intent of the code from what you've shown, so I can't suggest an alternative architecture.

Comment: Correct. The random number is only needed to make the buttons work.  Maybe this will help, I tried this but it didn't work (meaning the buttons don't alert John and Jane).  https://jsfiddle.net/2vqsmd4c/7/  But I feel like this is closer to being a cleaner way of accomplishing this because it doesn't result in multiple creations of whoAmI. I'm not allowed to post the real code plus it's entirely too long, but the concept here is the same. Instead of an object of people I have grid objects, the grids have buttons created by a string, and those buttons need to reference the correct grid instance

Comment: I don't know why you would need random numbers to make the buttons work. Please give a description of what you are trying to actually achieve because that will affect the design of any refinement or solution. E.g. do you just want a re-usable object that can render a button and output an alert given a string input? If so then the random generation stuff is just confusing the issue and can be stripped out.

Comment: It also feels to me like you maybe need to do a bit of reading on MVVM patterns and state-management for front-end coding. I get the feeling you are trying to use the DOM to store application state or application data, which is generally speaking a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed. I've used MVVM with ExtJS. This is an older project that is too large to re-write. All I can change is the code within the `runMe` function. The `obj` is a `DHTMLX` window, it gets passed into the singleton which adds content like grids, tabs, toolbars, forms, etc to the window. So the objects are windows with all sorts of content in them and many of these windows can be launched and open at the same time and rearranged on the screen, just like an OS. The singletons just add the content that goes into those windows. Issues arise when there is more than one instance of the same window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've stipulated that the only code you can/want to change is the `runMe` function, I would change your code to something like this:

```
window.mySingleton = {
    runMe: function(obj) {
        var xElement = document.getElementById('x');
        var button = document.createElement('input');
        button.type = 'button';
        button.value = 'Click Me';
        xElement.appendChild(button);
        button.onclick = function(){
          alert(obj.firstName);
        }
        // END OF CODE IN QUESTION
    }
};

//simulate launching panel xyz
var person1 = new Object();
person1.firstName = "John";
window['mySingleton']['runMe'](person1);

//simulate launching a second instance of panel xyz
var person2 = new Object();
person2.firstName = "Jane";
window['mySingleton']['runMe'](person2);
```

In this manner, you are setting the onClick to an actual function, instead of concatenating strings together to make elements that have string functions. This let's you call the function you've defined within `runMe` without having to actually attach that function to the global scope.

Edit: Forgot to add the jsfiddle. Here: https://jsfiddle.net/nzifnab/fkyLy3of/48/

Comment: This works, thanks! It's still cloudy to me as to why it matters how the button is created. You created it with script and I created it with a string and innerHTML. So long as the event gets added to it properly why would it matter how the button was created?  Example: why does this version not work? https://jsfiddle.net/6uLx1buu/4/  The onClick is being set to a function and added to the button just like your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this problem:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="x">

  </div>
<script>

    window.people = [];

    window.createButton = {

      init: function(obj) {
        document.getElementById('x').innerHTML += '<input type="button" onclick="window.createButton.show(' + obj.index + ')" value="Click Me">';
      },
      show: function(uid) {
        console.log(window.people);
        alert(window.people[uid].firstName);
      }
    };

    //simulate launching panel xyz
    var person1 = new Object();
    person1.firstName = "John";
    person1.index = window.people.length;
    window.people.push(person1);
    window.createButton.init(person1);

    //simulate launching a second instance of panel xyz
    var person2 = new Object();
    person2.firstName = "Jane";
    person2.index = window.people.length;
    window.people.push(person2);
    window.createButton.init(person2);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I've done is instead of creating a function for each person, I've created an array of people. So it's effectively a view-model (from the MVVM pattern). Then the `createButton` object is a single object which doesn't get cloned but just acts as a repository for your re-usable functions which are re-used by the widgets you've created at run-time.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r35zam1e/1/